# Pandas. Как заменить значение в DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Нужно в строке, содержащей определенное значение, произвести замену значения в ячейке, находящейся в другом столбце. Правильно ли я делаю, может есть другой более правильный способ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Вася', 'Петя'], 'B':[0, 0]})
df

Out[18]: 
      A  B
0  Вася  0
1  Петя  0

df.loc[df.A == 'Петя', 'B'] = 1
df

Out[20]: 
      A  B
0  Вася  0
1  Петя  1
```

Comment: Да, для данной задачи это, пожалуй, самый идиоматичный способ